# FindFirst to search for multiple values

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I have a listbox named listcomponents and each time the user can select multiple values. When the user selects the listbox the `Findfirst` operation is carried and the Machine System ID and the MachineSubsystem is calculated and based on these two the rs1![Machine Subsystem ID] is obtained. The value obtained in rs1![Machine Subsystem ID] is then again used in the condition for the next list box.

The problem is that the `FindFirst` operation only checks for the last stored value in rs1![Machine Subsystem ID] and not all the values which get generated (maybe because only the last value is stored in it). So is there a way I can get this to check for all the values that get generated in rs1![Machine Subsystem ID]. Here is the code:

```
   ID = DMax("[MAchine ID]", "tblmachine")

 Set db = CurrentDb()
 Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("tblMachineSystem", dbOpenDynaset, dbAppendOnly)
  Set rs1 = db.OpenRecordset("tblMachineSubSystem", dbOpenDynaset, 
 dbAppendOnly)
 Set rs2 = db.OpenRecordset("tblComponents", dbOpenDynaset, dbAppendOnly)
 Set rsmas = db.OpenRecordset("tblMasterData", dbOpenDynaset, dbAppendOnly)

 'add selected value(s) to table
Set ctl = Me.listMachineSystem
Set ctl1 = Me.listMachineSubSystem
Set ctl2 = Me.listComponents

For Each varItem In ctl.ItemsSelected
rs.AddNew
rs!MachineSystem = ctl.ItemData(varItem)
rs![MAchine ID] = ID
rs.Update
 Next varItem


   For i = 0 To Me.listMachineSubSystem.ListCount - 1
    If Me.listMachineSubSystem.Selected(i) Then
        rs.FindFirst "[Machine ID]=" & ID & " AND [MachineSystem]=  '" & DLookup(" 
        [MachineSystem]", "tblMachineSystem", "[Machine System ID]=" & 
        Me.listMachineSubSystem.Column(2, i)) & "'"
        rs1.AddNew
        rs1![MachineSubsystem] = Me.listMachineSubSystem.Column(0, i)
        rs1![Machine Sytem ID] = rs![Machine System ID]
        rs1.Update
    End If
    Next i
    For i = 0 To Me.listComponents.ListCount - 1
        If Me.listComponents.Selected(i) Then
            rs1.FindFirst "[Machine Sytem ID]=" & rs![Machine System ID] & " AND 
            [MachineSubsystem]=  '" & DLookup("[MachineSubsystem]", 
            "tblMachineSubSystem", 
            "[Machine Subsystem ID]=" & Me.listComponents.Column(2, i)) & "'"
            If rs1.NoMatch Then
                MsgBox "no records found"
            Else
                Do While Not rs1.NoMatch
                    MsgBox "i found it!!!"
                    rs1.FindNext "[Machine Sytem ID]=" & rs![Machine System ID] & " 
                    AND [MachineSubsystem]=  '" & DLookup("[MachineSubsystem]", 
                    "tblMachineSubSystem", "[Machine Subsystem ID]=" & 
                    Me.listComponents.Column(2, i)) & "'"
                Loop
                rs1.FindNext "[Machine Sytem ID]=" & rs![Machine System ID] & " AND 
                [MachineSubsystem]=  '" & DLookup("[MachineSubsystem]", 
                "tblMachineSubSystem", "[Machine Subsystem ID]=" & 
                Me.listComponents.Column(2, i)) & "'"
            End If
            rs2.AddNew
            rs2![Components] = Me.listComponents.Column(0, i)
            rs2![Machine Subsystem ID] = rs1![Machine Subsystem ID]
            rs2.Update
        End If
    Next i
```

I have two tables tblmMchineSubSystem with fiels and tblComponents and when the above code runs, I want the Machine Subsystem ID which is the primary key of tblmMchineSubSystem to be populated into the Machine Subsystem ID field of  tblComponents. The problem with the above code is that only the last value from the rs![Machine System ID] is checked in the findfirst function. I want all the values in rs![Machine System ID] to be checked by the `FindFirst` function.

The NEW CODE

```
   ID = DMax("[MAchine ID]", "tblmachine")
   Dim sMachineSubsystem As String, varSelectedID11 As Variant
   Dim vMaxMachineSubsystemID As Variant

   Set db = CurrentDb()
  Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("tblMachineSystem", dbOpenDynaset, dbAppendOnly)
   Set rs1 = db.OpenRecordset("tblMachineSubSystem", dbOpenDynaset, 
  dbAppendOnly)
 Set rs2 = db.OpenRecordset("tblComponents", dbOpenDynaset, dbAppendOnly)
 Set rsmas = db.OpenRecordset("tblMasterData", dbOpenDynaset, dbAppendOnly)

 Set ctl = Me.listMachineSystem
 Set ctl1 = Me.listMachineSubSystem
 Set ctl2 = Me.listComponents

'add selected value(s) from listMachineSystem to tblMachineSystem
For Each varItem In ctl.ItemsSelected
rs.AddNew
rs!MachineSystem = ctl.ItemData(varItem)
rs![MAchine ID] = ID
rs.Update
Next varItem

 For i = 0 To Me.listMachineSubSystem.ListCount - 1
 If Me.listMachineSubSystem.Selected(i) Then
  rs.FindFirst "[Machine ID]=" & ID & " AND [MachineSystem]=  '" & DLookup(" 
[MachineSystem]", "tblMachineSystem", "[Machine System ID]=" & 
 Me.listMachineSubSystem.Column(2, i)) & "'"

 rs1.AddNew
 rs1![MachineSubsystem] = Me.listMachineSubSystem.Column(0, i)
 rs1![Machine Sytem ID] = rs![Machine System ID]
 rs1.Update

    'Grab the maximum Machine System ID for the last selected item in the 
listMachineSubSystem list, for use in the next section
'To add components for every item selected in listMachineSubSystem, move the 
 entire below section of code to inside the previous section (so it's a loop 
 within a loop... be sure to rename i to something else)
  vMaxMachineSubsystemID = DMax("[Machine System ID]", "tblMachineSystem", " 
 [Machine ID]=" & ID & " AND [MachineSystem]=  '" & DLookup(" 
 [MachineSystem]", 
"tblMachineSystem", "[Machine System ID]=" & rs![Machine System ID]) & "'")

 'add selected value(s) from listComponents to tblComponents
 For l = 0 To Me.listComponents.ListCount - 1
  If Me.listComponents.Selected(l) Then
    varSelectedID2 = Me.listComponents.Column(2, l)
      sMachineSubsystem = DLookup("[MachineSubsystem]", 
"tblMachineSubSystem", "[Machine Subsystem ID]=" & varSelectedID2)

    rs1.FindFirst "[Machine Sytem ID]=" & vMaxMachineSubsystemID & " AND 
    [MachineSubsystem]=  '" & sMachineSubsystem & "'"
    If rs1.NoMatch Then
        MsgBox "no records found"
     Else
        Do While Not rs1.NoMatch
            MsgBox "I found it!!!"
            rs2.AddNew
            rs2![Components] = Me.listComponents.Column(0, l)
            rs2![Machine Subsystem ID] = rs1![Machine Subsystem ID]
            rs2.Update
            rs1.FindNext "[Machine Sytem ID]=" & vMaxMachineSubsystemID & " 
   AND [MachineSubsystem]=  '" & sMachineSubsystem & "'"
        Loop
    End If
   End If
  Next l
  End If
  Next i
```

Comment: You are almost certainly over-using or mis-using the `Find` functions. Try providing your table structure and a short description of what you are trying to do. I suspect code that generates SQL statements will be a lot more efficient in accomplishing your task than the way you try to do it with recordsets and Finds.

Comment: I have updated my question, since i cant embed pictures, i cant explain any clearer than above. hopefully you can see the above code and get what i am trying to do

Comment: Code should not even compile. Missing a `Next i`. An inner `For` loop cannot use the same index variable as outer `For` loop.  Where is the code that opens recordsets?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you set rs (without 1 or 2) to something earlier?

This seems very convoluted, and would result in a lot of unnecessary work for the machine. I'd add a TransactionID to the tblMachineSubSystem table, and then do something like:

```
dim MachineSystemID as variant, iMaxTransactionID as integer, iNewTransactionID as integer

Set rs1 = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM tblMachineSubSystem WHERE [Machine Sytem ID] = 1", dbOpenDynaset, dbAppendOnly) 'Saves time when all you want to do is add to the table

For i = 0 To Me.listMachineSubSystem.ListCount - 1
    If Me.listMachineSubSystem.Selected(i) Then
        MachineSystemID = DLookup("[Machine System ID]", "tblMachineSystem", "[Machine System ID]=" & Me.listMachineSubSystem.Column(2, i))
        iMaxTransactionID = DMax("[TransactionID]", "tblMachineSystem") 'Note that this logic assumes a single-user database, so there aren't multiple transactions going on at the same time
        rs1.AddNew
        rs1![MachineSubsystem] = Me.listMachineSubSystem.Column(0, i)
        rs1![Machine Sytem ID] = rs![Machine System ID]
        iNewTransactionID = iMaxTransactionID + 1
        rs1![TransactionID] = iNewTransactionID
        rs1.Update
    End If
Next i
rs1.Close

docmd.runsql "INSERT INTO tblComponents (Components, [Machine Subsystem ID]) SELECT MachineSubsystem, [Machine Subsystem ID] FROM tblMachineSubSystem WHERE TransactionID = " & iNewTransactionID
```

EDIT: Ok, here's the new version:

```
ID = DMax("[MAchine ID]", "tblmachine")
dim sMachineSubsystem as string, varSelectedID11 as variant
dim vMaxMachineSubsystemID as variant

Set db = CurrentDb()
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("tblMachineSystem", dbOpenDynaset, dbAppendOnly)
Set rs1 = db.OpenRecordset("tblMachineSubSystem", dbOpenDynaset, 
dbAppendOnly)
Set rs2 = db.OpenRecordset("tblComponents", dbOpenDynaset, dbAppendOnly)
Set rsmas = db.OpenRecordset("tblMasterData", dbOpenDynaset, dbAppendOnly)

Set ctl = Me.listMachineSystem
Set ctl1 = Me.listMachineSubSystem
Set ctl2 = Me.listComponents

'add selected value(s) from listMachineSystem to tblMachineSystem
For Each varItem In ctl.ItemsSelected
    rs.AddNew
    rs!MachineSystem = ctl.ItemData(varItem)
    rs![MAchine ID] = ID
    rs.Update
Next varItem

'add selected value(s) from listMachineSubSystem to tblMachineSubSystem
For i = 0 To Me.listMachineSubSystem.ListCount - 1
    If Me.listMachineSubSystem.Selected(i) Then
        varSelectedID1 = Me.listMachineSubSystem.Column(2, i)
        sMachineSubsystem = Me.listMachineSubSystem.Column(0, i)

        rs1.AddNew
        rs1![MachineSubsystem] = sMachineSubsystem
        rs1![Machine Sytem ID] = varSelectedID1
        rs1.Update
    End If
Next i

'Grab the maximum Machine System ID for the last selected item in the listMachineSubSystem list, for use in the next section
'To add components for every item selected in listMachineSubSystem, move the entire below section of code to inside the previous section (so it's a loop within a loop... be sure to rename i to something else)
vMaxMachineSubsystemID = DMax("[Machine System ID]", "tblMachineSystem", "[Machine ID]=" & ID & " AND [MachineSystem]=  '" & DLookup("[MachineSystem]", "tblMachineSystem", "[Machine System ID]=" & varSelectedID1) & "'")

'add selected value(s) from listComponents to tblComponents
For i = 0 To Me.listComponents.ListCount - 1
    If Me.listComponents.Selected(i) Then
        varSelectedID2 = Me.listComponents.Column(2, i)
        sMachineSubsystem = DLookup("[MachineSubsystem]", "tblMachineSubSystem", "[Machine Subsystem ID]=" & varSelectedID2)

        rs1.FindFirst "[Machine Sytem ID]=" & vMaxMachineSubsystemID & " AND [MachineSubsystem]=  '" & sMachineSubsystem & "'"
        If rs1.NoMatch Then
            MsgBox "no records found"
        Else
            Do While Not rs1.NoMatch
                MsgBox "I found it!!!"
                rs2.AddNew
                rs2![Components] = Me.listComponents.Column(0, i)
                rs2![Machine Subsystem ID] = rs1![Machine Subsystem ID]
                rs2.Update
                rs1.FindNext "[Machine Sytem ID]=" & vMaxMachineSubsystemID & " AND [MachineSubsystem]=  '" & sMachineSubsystem & "'"
            Loop
        End If
    End If
Next i
```

Comment: I have posted the same question in an other forum where i have embedded the pictures which will clearly explain my question. https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/29091983/VBA-Access-FindFirst-to-search-for-multiple-values.html?anchor=a42517469&notificationFollowed=205818768#a42517469.

Comment: Ah... ok, tbh, I'm even more confused now. Perhaps it would help to know the rowsource of your listboxes? Also, your code here in stackexchange is incomplete (it's missing the entire first part).

Comment: I have updated the code and the row source type  for all the listboxes is a value list except for the first list box which gets the values from tblMachine. I have embedded pictures of all four tables in the link https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/29091983/VBA-Access-FindFirst-to-search-for-multiple-values.html

Comment: This question is extremely confusing, and like other commenters, I suspect the FindFirst is not what you should be using. I think the question needs some major reworking. A user picks multiple values from a listbox that pulls from tblMachine, and you want to do what with the values? Walk me through it. You want to loop through the list of selected values, assign the current selection to a variable, and then do what with that variable?

Comment: NM... Ok, you want to add the selected values to tblMachineSystem. Then you want to iterate through the selected values in listMachineSubSystem, and find the associated value from tblMachineSystem, and see if it exists in tblMachineSystem, and then add the resulting... what?? Sorry... this is just so convoluted. But I think I can figure it out. Will update my answer shortly.

Comment: Ok, I've edited my answer. Hopefully this is closer to what you're looking for. It's still quite strange, actually, so I'm not sure if you wanted all selected machine subsystems figured into the add code for the components table, or just the maximum one for the last item selected, but I commented what to do if you want them all.

Comment: Hi, Thanks a lot for the code , the code u wrote was not exactly what i wanted , but i modified it a bit and it works perfectly and i have copied the modified code above. THE ID's are perfectly populating , i just have one problem , some of the selections repeat twice as shown in the pic in tblComponents. link https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/29091983/VBA-Access-FindFirst-to-search-for-multiple-values.html  . I am not able to figure out why , would really appreciate if you would help me out on that.

Comment: Hi, can anyone help me on this, i have still not been able to find a solution for avoiding the duplicates creation